# How to deal with Google recaptcha backend validation response delay

Tags: angular

```
<re-captcha
      class="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey={{captchaSiteKey}}>
</re-captcha>
<button>submit</buttton>
```

When the user clicks the recaptcha and completes it then `resolved` method runs and it checkes if the resonse was correct from the backend. Since its a must to also verify the response in the backend to be completely secure.It takes about 1 to 1.5 seconds for the backend response to come. When the user clicks the submit button in the form instantly it doesn't work because `this.captchaResponse` is false and its only becomes true after the response from the server comes after 1 to 1.5 second so sometimes the user has to click the submit button in the form twice.
I dont think we could customize google recaptcha check mark animation and add 1 to 2 seconds to it because the check mark completes before the backend response arrives it related to frontend response only so it gives an illusion to the user that recaptcha validation has completed but in reality it only completes  1 to 1.5 seconds later when the backend response comes.

```
resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
        console.log(captchaResponse)
        if(captchaResponse !== null) {
          this.data.verifyCaptcha(captchaResponse).subscribe((res: any)=>{
            if(res.success) {
              this.captchaResponse = true;
            }
          });
        } else {
          this.captchaResponse = false;
        }

        onSubmit() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.submitted = true;
            if (this.loginForm.invalid || !this.captchaResponse) {
                this.loading = false;
                return;
            }
            let frmData = this.loginForm.value;
        }
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the form's submit until this.captchaResponse is true instead of allow the submit before the captcha is resolved and your service returns a proper value. Something like

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!captchaResponse">Send</button>
```

Comment: I have thought about doing it but also seen other website which implement google recaptcha don't have this problem and their submit is also enabled all the time

Comment: You can create an Observable and amit true/false when your backend returns a value. And in the submit method, subscribe to it.

The main problem is that your flow is asynchronous, so you have to deal with this (using Observables, Promises,a  callback, etc...). Note that the problem does not have anything to do with the Repatcha, but with this request to the backend.